# Server rendering with react-router v4 and prefetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-rendering

I worked a lot with server side rendering with RR 3 so I wanted to see how it works in the context of v4. I followed the tutorial from the website, but because the rendering is happening now together with the route match, there's no way to implement prefetching data as before.

Here's how I used to do server rendering with v3:
https://github.com/alexnm/react-seed/blob/master/server/index.js

Based on the match function, I would call all the prefetch functions from all the component tree and then wait with a `Promise.all` for them to finish, then trigger the `renderToString` function and return the html.

In RR4, we have only the `<ServerRouter>` component, so the current solution I came with is duplicating the render code:
https://github.com/FortechRomania/react-redux-complete-example/blob/master/src/server/index.js

I'm also using the `render` function on the `<Match>` tag to trigger the prefetch actions. It's ugly and introduces all sorts of dependencies in the parent component of the page I want to render with prefetched data.

What am I missing here? Has anyone found a better solution for this scenario? I haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: Got exactly the same problem :/ There's no official example yet or any tutorials how to do it... Your solution is the only one I found - thanks!

Comment: I plan on digging some more into this the coming weeks, will come back with an answer if I find any

Comment: For now I switched the codebase to v3, but the question is still valid for the new v4 beta api

Comment: It's possible that there will some more official solution soon: https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/832268350206078976

Comment: We have a working solution now

Comment: @AlexMoldovan would you mind sharing your solution please?

Comment: posted a link to the documentation below

Comment: What about If you can't use static route config AlexMoldovan?

Comment: can you give me an example to understand what you are referring to?

Answer (score -1):

The new RR4 documentation has a working example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering/data-loading